# How Do i Randomly Select an Item From A List?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, import

i was curious on how to randomly select an item from a list? for example you want to randomly choose an item from a list to print something. In the example code below i make a list with random items in it and i want the print to say "the random item is" and then a random item from the list. Sorry if this is a bit unclear if you want me to explain it better just ask :) Thanks

```
#Example
random = ["random1", "random2", "random3"]
print("Random item is " + "Random Item"???)
```

Comment: It's definitely a duplicate.

Comment: The accepted answer here is the same as the accepted answer given in the question linked above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import random
items = ["random1", "random2", "random3"]
random.choice(items)
```

Comment: Please do a search for duplicates before answering common questions like this. FWIW, the question linked by juanpa.arrivillaga already had 37 duplicate links, we really don't need another one.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
list = ["random1", "random2", "random3"]
random.choice(list)
```

The `random.choice(list)` returns one of the items in the list, which means you can do this:

```
import random
list = ["random1", "random2", "random3"]
chosen = random.choice(list)
print("The chosen was: {}".format(chosen))
```